# Exchange 2019 On-Prem Receive Connector Issue

Tags: exchange

I'm in the middle of migration right now from Exchange 2016 to Exchange 2019 on-prem. Everything works except for Receive connectors. Whenever I send an email to local exchange users from outside (i.e. GMail, Yahoo, MS365), the local exchange user didn't receive it. When I checked the Queue viewer, the receive connector is still trying to use the Exchange 2016. How can I force or make sure to use the Exchange 2019 receive connector?

Comment: Can you please provide more information with PowerShell cmdlet get-recieveconnector. I think you need to disabled or remove the 2016 connector and update mx records and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by rerunning the Hybrid configuration wizard. thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, local Exchange users cannot receive emails sent from outside. It is recommended that you confirm the following information to better troubleshoot where the problem occurs:

1. Whether the sender has received the NDR information
2. Which server is the Queue viewer viewing on? Exchange server 2016 or 2019? What is the complete error message?
3. Check whether the MX record points to exchange server 2019.

In addition, if there is no user mailbox on Exchange Server 2016, you can directly disable the receive connector and restart the Microsoft Exchange Transport service on the Exchange 2019 server. For details, please refer to [Set-ReceiveConnector (ExchangePowerShell) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-receiveconnector?view=exchange-ps)

Comment: I am writing here to confirm with you how the thing going now? Do you perhaps have any questions regarding the information provided?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, glad to know you have solved the problem.